# Can't import package produced by wasm-pack in nodejs + ESM + typescript

Tags: javascript, webassembly, wasm-pack

I am trying to import a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fhe-wasm) which I published and which is generated using `wasm-pack`. This is the source code of the Rust project. I tried building the package with all the target options but none of those seems to produce a package which I could successfully import in my nodejs project with ESM. Then I tried modifying the package.json file manually so that it follows what in my understanding an ESM library needs and it looks as follows:

```
{
  "name": "fhe-wasm",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "type": "module",
  "exports": "./fhe_wasm.js",
  "files": [
    "fhe_wasm_bg.wasm",
    "fhe_wasm.js",
    "fhe_wasm.d.ts"
  ],
  "module": "fhe_wasm.js",
  "types": "fhe_wasm.d.ts",
  "sideEffects": false
}
```

Unfortunately I still didn't manage to successfully import it and the and this is the error message:
[image]

I am a bit of a noob with ESM and webassembly so I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was being stupid and didn't realize that I can simply import CommonJS library when using ESM. Simply running `wasm-pack build -t nodejs` produced a library I could use.